# Is there any reason not to upgrade to Windows 8.1?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, compatibility, windows-8.1

I have the option to upgrade to 8.1, but before I do I want to see if anyone has had any compatibility issues. I mainly run ESRI, but occasionally use QGIS, and other open source products. Has anyone ran into any compatibility issues with 8.1 and any GIS software?

Comment: Can't comment on QGIS but you need at least 10.2.1 if you are going to upgrade to Windows 8.1

Comment: Minimum QGIS version I've tried which works on Windows 8.1 is QGIS 2.2 but the latest version of QGIS (2.6) also works fine. But even without compatibility issues with GIS softwares, I personally wouldn't upgrade to Windows 8.1 (waste of money if you ask me!).

Comment: You can't dual-boot with Ubuntu...

Comment: I'm currently running ArcGIS 10.2.2 and ArcPro Pre-release on Windows 8.1 update (Surface Pro 3) and they run as well there as on my Windows 7 64 bit.  I haven't used QGIS much on the 8.1 Update Surface Pro, but 2.4 ran fine when I did.  QGIS 2.6 installed okay on another 8.1 update machine but it hasn't really been tested on it beyond opening and viewing some datasets. I haven't had any compatibility issues with any of my software on 8.1 update.

Comment: Personally, I am skipping the whole Windows 8 train wreck. Windows 7 is working fine so no reason to upgrade.  If you do any custom add-in development, I would advise to make sure that VS express 2010 can still be installed and functioning and that tools compile and work correctly in Windows 8.1.

Comment: @mapBaker I have been running a dual boot of Ununtu 12.04 LTS and Windows8.1 for about a year without a problem.

Comment: @TingL please share that info because a few of us had huge issues and read a lot of forum posts that documented the change Windows 8 made to the boot loader process basically eliminating the ability to load Ubuntu on dual-boot... thanks!

Comment: @mapBaker It's been a while. As far as I can remember, I shrank the hard drive to make some space for Ubuntu, custom partitioned the new space during installation into 250M for /boot , the rest of the space for / except the swap space. My computer came with Windows 8. I may have installed Ubuntu while it was 8, and then upgraded to 8.1. Also, I remember having to pay attention to whether the computer came with UEFI or the old traditional BIOS. I had some issues with UEFI in the past on other dualboot, and turned that computer into BIOS as I didn't have time to solve the UEFI issue.

Comment: thanks @TingL - I'll see if we can fix the issue, but what you've described is still definitely a headache for most users...